# Melhor maneira de fazer um script para logout

Tags: php, session, login

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema em que ele é acessado com o login e senha, uma vez logado o usuário tem a opção de fazer o logout, segue abaixo o meu script:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['logado'])){
    session_destroy();
    header("Location:index.php");
}
```

Quero saber, se essa é uma maneira correta de ser fazer isso, sendo que este código esta num arquivo separado

Aqui esta o botao que faz o logout

```
echo " <a href='doLogout.php'>Sair</a>";
```

Comment: Sim, se o login só usa sessões, são elas que devem ser destruídas. Se houver cookie, eles também devem ser destruídos.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Um problema adicional nesse Logout, além do que já foi mencionado pelo @PapaCharlie, é que qualquer link de fora para a página de logout complica a experiência do usuário. Do jeito que está, basta um clique acidental no histórico ou um autocompletar errado e o cara fica "escapando" da sessão "deslogando" sem querer.

Além disso, algum "concorrente" malicioso poderia forçar seus usuários a perderem a sessão constantemente com um mero link invisível em outros sites (exemplo: `<script src="http://seusite/caminhodologout">`).

Ideal se essa página de logout recebesse um parâmetro que identificasse a sessão. Se receber, faz o logout, se não receber, ela mostra "Confirma o logout?" e no SIM usa um link com o parâmetro, assim, um link "velho" pro logout não funcionaria.

### Exemplo simplificado de solução:

Link de logout:

```
echo '<a href="doLogout.php?token='.md5(session_id()).'">Sair</a>';
// sim, MD5 é seguro suficiente nesse contexto (e é apenas exemplo).
```

Página de logout:

```
session_start();
$token = md5(session_id());
if(isset($_GET['token']) && $_GET['token'] === $token) {
   // limpe tudo que for necessário na saída.
   // Eu geralmente não destruo a seção, mas invalido os dados da mesma
   // para evitar algum "necromancer" recuperar dados. Mas simplifiquemos:
   session_destroy();
   header("location: http://exemplo.com.br/index.php");
   exit();
} else {
   echo '<a href="doLogout.php?token='.$token.'>Confirmar logout</a>';
}
```

Comment: Gostei desse seu método, teste aqui no meu e funcionou.

Answer (score 4):

Geralmente o login é uma combinação de sessões e cookies que garantem a autenticidade do usuário mesmo após o navegador fechar. Supondo um sistema simples de login com uso unico de sessões, você tem 2 exemplos abaixo. Atente-se para chamar a função `session_start` no momento certo.

1) Se você possui uma página só para logout, basta você pode usar desta forma:

```
session_start();
session_destroy();
header("location: http://www.dominio.com.br/index.php");
```

2) Se sua aplicação é diferente do exemplo acima, você pode usar:

```
session_start(); // previamente chamada
```

Removendo as sessões

```
if(isset($_SESSION['logado'])){
    // se você possui algum cookie relacionado com o login deve ser removido
    session_destroy();
    header("location: http://www.dominio.com.br/index.php");
    exit();
}
```